# In GAP, how can I generate a specific diagonal subgroup of the direct product two groups?

Tags: group-theory, gap

Let $P$ and $Q$ be isomorphic subgroups of a finite group $G$, let $\phi$ be an isomorphism from $P$ to $Q$. How can I find the subgroup of DirectProduct(G, G) that corresponds this set $\{(a,b)\in G\times G : b = \phi(a), a\in P\}$ in GAP?

Comment: Won't this just be an isomorphic image of $P$ again?

Comment: Yes, it will be.

Comment: Depending on the intended application, representing it as the image of $P$ might be sufficient.  A sketch of the context could help Readers form more useful responses.

Comment: @hardmath This question is asking for something very precise, so I am not sure what you mean by saying that the image of $P$ might be sufficient. The question makes perfect sense already (and it has now been answered).

Comment: @DerekHolt: I'm an upvoter for the Question, but the construction makes me wonder if $\phi$ extends to an endomorphism of $G$.  The Answer posted uses $G$ to mean $P\times Q$ instead of how the Question posits $P,Q \subset G$.

Comment: @hardmath Yes you are right! I was also assuming that $P$ and $Q$ were genuine subgroups of $G$ rather than just isomporphic to them. So an accurate would require those isomorphisms to be specified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not particularly efficient, but it should work. In the following, `P` and `Q` are groups, and `iso` is an isomorphism from P to Q.

```
G := DirectProduct(P, Q);
embP := Embedding(G, 1);
embQ := Embedding(G, 2);
gensImageP := List(GeneratorsOfGroup(P), x -> Image(embP, x));
gensImageQ := List(GeneratorsOfGroup(P), x -> Image(embQ,x^iso));
gensDiag := List([1..Length(gensImageP)], 
                 y -> gensImageP[y] * gensImageQ[y]);
diag := Group(gensDiag);
```

Comment: There is nothing inefficient here -- that's exactly how to do it and it will be fast.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I don't do much programming these days, so it was conceivable that I was missing something.